# Dropdown navbar menu on my Django/Bootstrap 4 website works everywhere except on the home page

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

As the title says, I have a dropdown menu on my site. At first it *only* worked on the homepage and nowhere else until I realised I didn't include the link to the Bootstrap JavaScript framework in the base.html file. So I included it and now the dropdown menu works everywhere except on the homepage. I feel like this is a simple fix and is just staring me in the face but it has me stumped. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>TUD Cinemas</title>
    <!-- My own CSS Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Google font link -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">
                <img src="/static/images/TUDC_logo.png" class="luke_logo">
            </a>


            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'movies' %}">What's on</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog' %}">Blog</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'news' %}">News</a>
                </li>

                {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <!-- Dropdown Menu -->


                <li class="nav-item dropdown multi-level-dropdown">
                    <a href="#" id="menu" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle w-100">Account</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu mt-0 rounded-0 bg-light primary-color border-0 z-depth-1">

                        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu p-1">
                            <a class="w-100">
                                {{ request.user.username }}
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu p-1">
                            {% with total_items=cart|length %}
                            {% if cart|length > 0 %}

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="{% url 'cart:cart_detail' %}" class="w-100">
                                Your Cart:
                                {{ total_items }} item{{ total_items|pluralize }}:
                                €{{ cart.get_total_price }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu p-1">
                            <a class="w-100">Cart: (0)</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endwith %}
                </li>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu p-1">
                    <a href="{% url 'orders:order_history' %}" class="w-100">Your Tickets</a>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu p-1">
                    <a href="{% url 'signout' %}" class="w-100">Sign Out</a>
                </li>

            </ul>



            {% else %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'signin' %}">Log In</a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}

            </ul>




            <ul class=" nav navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'search_result' %}" method="get">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholders="Search" aria-label="Search"
                        name="q">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>




            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container basecontainer bg-light">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the homepage.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>New Carousel</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="MyCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- The slideshow -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <a href="{% url 'movies' %}">
                    <img src="static/images/raidersOfTheLostArk-homepage.jpeg" alt="raidersOfTheLostArk" width="1100" height="450">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <a href="{% url 'movies'%}">
                    <img src="static/images/pulpfiction-homepage.jpeg" alt="pulp fiction" width="1100" height="450">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <a href="{% url 'movies'%}">
                    <img src="static/images/joker-homepage.jpeg" alt="joker" width="1100" height="450">
                </a>              
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <a href="{% url 'movies'%}">
                    <img src="static/images/theshining-homepage.jpeg" alt="the shining" width="1100" height="450">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <a href="{% url 'movies'%}">
                    <img src="static/images/avatar-homepage.jpeg" alt="avatar" width="1100" height="450">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <a href="{% url 'movies'%}">
                    <img src="static/images/starwarsep4-homepage.jpeg" alt="star wars" width="1100" height="450">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#MyCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#MyCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

</body>
<div class="row my-4">


    <div class="col-sm-5 homepagecards">
        <a href="{% url 'campus_list' %}" class="">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2>Browse Movies By Campus</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>See what's showing in your local TUD cinema!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <span class="col-sm-2 mt-3">
        <img src="static/images/tickets.png" class="col-sm-12">
    </span>

    <div class="col-sm-5 homepagecards">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2>Browse Categories</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>Find a movie that suits your liking by browsing specific categories!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <img src="/static/images/cinema_front_2.jpg" class="banner_image rounded">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid mt-3">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">

        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center mt-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2 class="text-center">
                        Select a campus.
                    </h2>
                </div>
                {% for campus in campuses %}
                <div class="card-body py-2 border-bottom campus-names homepagecards">
                    {% if campus.name == "TUD Tallaght" %}
                    <a href="{% url 'screen_movies' campus.id %}">
                        <p class="mt-2">{{campus.name}}</p>
                    </a>
                    {% elif campus.name == "TUD City" %}
                    <a href="{% url 'screen_movies' campus.id %}">
                        <p class="mt-2">{{campus.name}}</p>
                    </a>
                    {% elif campus.name == "TUD Blanchardstown" %}
                    <a href="{% url 'screen_movies' campus.id %}">
                        <p class="mt-2">{{campus.name}}</p>
                    </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <span class="col-sm-1"></span>

        <div class="col-sm-3">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Again any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Navbar and dropdown` depend on `jQuery` and `popper.js`, so you must include both js `scripts` with `bootstrap.js` in the described order.

**Structure & Order**

```
<head>
    ...All Tags
    Bootstrap CSS Link Tag
</head>
<body>
    ...All Tags
    jQuery Script Tag
    Popper JS Script Tag
    Bootstrap JS Script Tag
</body>
```

**Example**

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!